# Updating options in optionmenu Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, updating, optionmenu

I am currently writing  on a small hobby project and I have a problem concerning my list "dice" while using the dropdown menu it only ever shows the first iteration of the list (the single 0) but it is supposed to be updated in the dropdown menu after each press of the "roll the dice" button. How do I do that?

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Hobbyprojekt')

count = -1
global dice
dice = [0]
prpp= IntVar() 
diceshow=Label()
#defining funtions for buttons 
def roll():
    global count
    global diceshow
    global dice
    count +=1
    print(count)
    if count >= 1:
        dice=[]
    for x in range (0,7) :
        dice.append(randint(1,10))
    
    #calculating the viable dice options
    for x in range (0,2) :
        dice.remove(min(dice))

    if count >= 1:
        diceshow.destroy()
        print("destroyed")
    
    diceshow=Label(root, text=dice)
    diceshow.grid(row=0,column=1)
    print(dice)
    print(dice[1])
    print(dice[2])
    print(dice[3])

#setting up the test gui
button1 = Button(root, text='Roll the dice', command=roll)
label1= Label(text='choice1')
label2= Label(text='choice2')
label3= Label(text='choice3')
label4= Label(text='choice4')
label5= Label(text='choice5')
label6= Label(text='choice6')
dd1= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
dd2= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
dd3= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
dd4= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
dd5= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
dd6= OptionMenu(root,prpp,*dice)
#setting layout
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
label2.grid(row=2,column=0)
label3.grid(row=3,column=0)
label4.grid(row=4,column=0)
label5.grid(row=5,column=0)
label6.grid(row=6,column=0)
dd1.grid(row=1, column=1)
dd2.grid(row=2,column=1)
dd3.grid(row=3,column=1)
dd4.grid(row=4,column=1)
dd5.grid(row=5,column=1)
dd6.grid(row=6,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

So i'm acctually lost for ideas on what to do since i am fairly new to python. Only thing i could think of is creating the dropdown menus within the "diceroll" button definition but that is not reall what  would want to do. Thanks in advance.

edit: fixed spelling.

Comment: I don't understand what the six dropdowns are for because they use same variable `prpp` (that means changing one of them will change the others as well) and have only one option `0`. Also it is not clear what do you want to update on those dropdowns when the button is clicked.

Comment: you are right, they are for diffrent choices and i haden't changed the variable names in this itteration. what i want to update is: if i choose an option in the first drop down the choosen ooption should not be choosable in the other dropdown menues... but as far as is found out the dropdown menue acctually has no update funktion. so i need to do a work around with destroying the original dropdowns everytime one option is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this is what you want? I moved `optionmenu` into `roll()` function

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Hobbyprojekt')

count = -1
#global dice
dice = [0]
prpp= IntVar() 
diceshow=Label()
#defining funtions for buttons 
def roll():
    global count
    global diceshow
    global dice
    count +=1
    print(count)
    if count >= 1:
        dice=[]
    for x in range (0,7) :
        dice.append(randint(1,10))
    
    #calculating the viable dice options
    for x in range (0,2) :
        dice.remove(min(dice))

    if count >= 1:
        diceshow.destroy()
        print("destroyed")
    
    diceshow=Label(root, text=dice)
    diceshow.grid(row=0,column=1)
    print(dice)
    print(dice[1])
    print(dice[2])
    print(dice[3])
    dd1= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[0])
    dd2= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[1])
    dd3= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[2])
    dd4= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[3])
    dd5= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[4])
    dd6= OptionMenu(root,prpp,dice[5])

    dd1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    dd2.grid(row=2,column=1)
    dd3.grid(row=3,column=1)
    dd4.grid(row=4,column=1)
    dd5.grid(row=5,column=1)
    dd6.grid(row=6,column=1)

    

#setting up the test gui
button1 = Button(root, text='Roll the dice', command=roll)
label1= Label(text='choice1')
label2= Label(text='choice2')
label3= Label(text='choice3')
label4= Label(text='choice4')
label5= Label(text='choice5')
label6= Label(text='choice6')
 
#setting layout
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
label2.grid(row=2,column=0)
label3.grid(row=3,column=0)
label4.grid(row=4,column=0)
label5.grid(row=5,column=0)
label6.grid(row=6,column=0)
 

root.mainloop()
```

Result before:

[image]

Result after:

[image]

Comment: Yea this is what i ended uo doing, since there is no update funktionality coneccted to the dropdown menu's.